# Showing a list of events in a D3 map

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to make a map in D3 of Amsterdam. The map shows points where festivals are held. Now, the map is divided by neighbourhoods. When I now hover my mouse over a neighbourhood, it shows the name of it. But what I want is that is shows the name and all the names of the festivals.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>


    <style>

    .province {
        fill: #000;
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-width: 1px;
    }
    .province:hover {
        fill: #666;
    }
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
    div.tooltip {
        color: #222;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: .5em;
        text-shadow: #f5f5f5 0 1px 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        opacity: 0.9;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>




</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

/*Variabelen die in de code worden gebruikt. */  
var width = 1000;
var height = 600;
var xy = d3.geo.mercator()
          .scale(100000)
          .center([4.9, 52.36]) 
          .translate([width / 2, height / 2]); 
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
            .attr('class', 'hidden tooltip');


/*Hier wordt de kaart van Amsterdam ingeladen */        

d3.json("amsterdam.json", function(data) {


    var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
        .data(data.features)  
        .enter()
        .append("g")


    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                    .scale(100000)
                    .center([4.9, 52.36]) 
                    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]); 

    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection); 


    var areas = group.append("path")
        .attr("d", path) 
        .attr("class", "amsterdam")
            .attr("fill", "grey");

    var path = d3.geo.path()
                .projection(projection);
    var provinces = canvas.selectAll('.province')
                .data(data.features).enter();
            provinces.append('path')
                .attr('class', function(d,i) {
                    return 'province ' + d.properties.name;
                })
                .attr('d', path)
                .on('mousemove', function(d) {
                    var mouse = d3.mouse(canvas.node()).map(function(d) {
                        return parseInt(d);
                    });
                    tooltip.classed('hidden', false)
                        .attr('style', 'left:' + (mouse[0] + 15) +
                                'px; top:' + (mouse[1] - 35) + 'px')
                        .html(d.properties.name);
                })
                .on('mouseout', function() {
                    tooltip.classed('hidden', true);
                });

});

/*Vanaf hier worden de festivals ingeladen*/

d3.csv("Festivals.csv", function(d) { 



  var node = canvas.selectAll("circle")
    .data(d)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xy([+d["Longitude"],+d["Latitude"]])[0]; })
      .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return xy([+d["Longitude"],+d["Latitude"]])[1]; })
      .attr("r", "4.5px")
      .attr("fill", "orange")
      .style("opacity", .5)
      .append("title")
      .text(function(d) {return d.Title});





});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

festivals.csv (first 2)

```
    Trcid,Title,Shortdescription,Longdescription,Calendarsummary,TitleEN,ShortdescriptionEN,LongdescriptionEN,CalendarsummaryEN,Types,Ids,Locatienaam,City,Adres,Zipcode,Latitude,Longitude,Urls,Media,Thumbnail,Datepattern_startdate,Datepattern_enddate,Singledates,Type1,Lastupdated
b3148e78-f653-484d-a069-9cd4b6cf924c,Amsterdam Salsa Festival,Ondanks de kou buiten krijg je het vanzelf warm bij het jaarlijkse Amsterdam Salsa Festival. ,<strong>Drie dagen vol salsa<br /> </strong>Het festival. georganiseerd door het Meininger Hotel. belooft drie dagen vol dansworkshops. optredens van Nederlandse en internationale dansers en een geweldig themafeest.&nbsp:<br /> Bekijk te zijner tijd de <a target=&quot:_blank&quot: href=&quot:http://www.amsterdamsalsafestival.nl/#!/home&quot: re_target=&quot:_blank&quot:>Amsterdam Salsa Festival website</a> voor meer informatie en kaartverkoop.,Vr 10 februari 2017 23:00 - 05:00 uur. za 11 februari 2017 23:00 - 05:00 uur. zo 12 februari 2017 23:00 - 04:00 uur. Toelichting: Data onder voorbehoud.,Amsterdam Salsa Festival,It may still be a bit chilly outside. but you?re sure to feel the heat at the annual Amsterdam Salsa Festival.,<h2>Three days of Salsa in Amsterdam<strong></strong></h2> <strong></strong>The <strong>Amsterdam Salsa Festival</strong> promises three packed days of <strong>dance workshops</strong>. <strong>performances</strong> by Dutch and international dancers and a <strong>blowout theme party</strong> on Saturday night at the Rhone Congress &amp: Party Centre.<br /> <br /> Head to the <a target=&quot:_blank&quot: href=&quot:http://www.amsterdamsalsafestival.nl/#!/home&quot: re_target=&quot:_blank&quot:>Amsterdam Salsa Festival website</a> for more information and tickets nearer the time.,Fr 10 February 2017 23:00 - 05:00 hour. Sa 11 February 2017 23:00 - 05:00 hour. Su 12 February 2017 23:00 - 04:00 hour. Explanation: Date to be confirmed.,,2.4.1,Sloterdijk,AMSTERDAM,Rhoneweg 12-14,1043 AH,52.390416,4.831372,http://www.amsterdamsalsafestival.nl,https://media.iamsterdam.com/ndtrc/Images/20140416/c9aa34cb-5c23-4591-bc50-8308223d6008.jpg,https://media.iamsterdam.com/ndtrc/Images/20140416/c9aa34cb-5c23-4591-bc50-8308223d6008.jpg,,,10-02-2017.11-02-2017.12-02-2017,,22-2-2016 15:53

225e629a-da76-4012-97db-a47ed088722f,Chinees Nieuwjaar,In 2017 valt het Chinees Nieuwjaar op 28 januari. De meeste activiteiten tijdens het Chinees Nieuwjaar vinden volgens traditie in Amsterdam plaats bij de Nieuwmarkt en de Zeedijk. maar er zijn doorgaans ook feestelijkheden op de Dam.,<h2>Gong Xi Fa Cai! (Gelukkig nieuwjaar!)</h2> Het <strong>Chinees Nieuwjaar</strong>. oftewel het Lunar Nieuwjaar. is het belangrijkste event op de Chinese kalender en wordt wereldwijd gevierd. Op deze dag komen Chinezen met de hele familie. staan rituelen met eten. offers bij tempels en de kleur rood centraal. Bijgelovige personen kunnen hun hart ophalen bij Chinees Nieuwjaar: volgens de Chinezen kun je je namelijk gelukkig eten. Zo staat er standaard <em>yu sheng</em> (rauwe vissalade ) en <em>fai-hai</em> (zeewier) op het menu. die beiden voor geluk en voorspoed zorgen.<br /> <br /> <h2>Het Jaar van de Aap in Amsterdam</h2> 2016 is het Jaar van de Aap. In 2016 vinden de <strong>offici&euml:le feestelijkheden voor het Chinees Nieuwjaar</strong> waarschijnlijk opnieuw op <strong>de Dam</strong> plaats. met honderdduizendklappers om de kwade geesten te verjagen. De Leeuwendans vindt doorgaans plaats bij de <a href=&quot:http://www.iamsterdam.com/nl/uit-in-amsterdam/zien-en-doen/musea-en-galeries/musea-in-amsterdam/beurs-van-berlage&quot:>Beurs van Berlage</a> en <a href=&quot:http://www.iamsterdam.com/nl/uit-in-amsterdam/zien-en-doen/shoppen/overzicht-warenhuizen/de-bijenkorf&quot:>de Bijenkorf</a>. De Bijenkorf organiseert volgens traditie ook jaarlijks speciale activiteiten om Chinees Nieuwjaar te vieren.<br /> <br /> <h2>Chinatown Amsterdam</h2> In de Amsterdamse Chinese <strong>Nieuwmarktbuurt</strong> staat een echte <strong>boeddhistische tempel</strong>: de Fo Guang Shan He Hua. Bij de Chinese tempel vindt jaarlijks de Chinese nieuwjaarsviering plaats.&nbsp:Mocht je trek krijgen van al het spektakel dan kun je je tegoed doen aan Chinees eten. bij bijvoorbeeld het drijvende Chinese restaurant Sea Palace op de Oosterdokskade. Ook aan de Stormsteeg en de Geldersekade zitten veel Chinese restaurants.,Za 28 januari 2017 09:00 - 20:00 uur.,Chinese New Year,In 2017. Chinese New Year falls on 28 January. Festivities traditionally take place on Amsterdam's Dam Square and around the historic Nieuwmarkt/Zeedijk neighbourhood on the Saturday nearest New Year.,<h2>Year of the Monkey in Amsterdam</h2> 2016 is the Year of the Monkey. <strong>Amsterdam's Chinese New Year celebrations</strong> in 2016 took place on <strong>Dam Square</strong> and around the <strong>Nieuwmarkt</strong> (<strong>Amsterdam's Chinatown area</strong>). There were dragon and lion dances as well as fireworks.  <a href=&quot:http://www.iamsterdam.com/en/visiting/what-to-do/shopping/overview-department-stores/de-bijenkorf-luxury-department-store&quot:>De Bijenkorf</a> department  store traditionally organises special activities to celebrate Chinese New Year. including in-store dragon and lion dances. calligraphy workshops. music performances and tea ceremonies. <br /> <h2>A taste of China</h2> If you&rsquo:re looking for something more intimate. retreat to the Fo Guang Shan He Hua. a real Buddhist temple which usually has a special programme. Alternatively. grab yourself a meal at the Sea Palace (Europe&rsquo:s first floating Chinese restaurant) or at one of the many Chinese restaurants along the Stormsteeg and Geldersekade.<br /> <br /> <h2>Gong Xi Fa Cai! (Happy New Year!)</h2> <strong>Chinese New Year</strong>. also known as the Lunar New Year. is the most important event in the Chinese calendar. It&rsquo:s a special occasion whichever part of the world you&rsquo:re in. and nearly always marked by family gatherings. food rituals. offerings at temples and the colour red. The superstitious will particularly enjoy Chinese New Year&rsquo:s Eve. when a raw fish salad (yu sheng) is said to bring good luck and fai-hai. a type of seaweed. prosperity. (The vegetarian option is lettuce. which the Chinese believe sounds like 'luck').,Sa 28 January 2017 09:00 - 20:00 hour.,,2.4.1,Burgwallen-Oude Zijde,AMSTERDAM,Dam 1,1012 JS,52.373561,4.894367,,https://media.iamsterdam.com/ndtrc/Images/20130110/c88bba81-ec5c-4179-89dc-`f932e0c772a0.jpg,https://media.iamsterdam.com/ndtrc/Images/20130110/c88bba81-ec5c-4179-89dc-f932e0c772a0.jpg,,,28-1-2017,,4-3-2016 13:59
```

Can anyone help me? I'm struggling with this for ages...

Comment: in your `festivals.csv`, is there any description of the provinces? Maybe "locatienaam"?

Comment: It is called name. type": "Feature", "id": 2, "properties": { "name": "Grachtengordel-West" }

Comment: Not in the `json`, I'm asking about the `csv`.

Comment: No, only the coordinates,

Comment: The locatienaam isn't the name of a province.

Comment: In that case, it will be way more complicated. If you had the name of the province for each festival (in a new comma separated value), it'd be easier.

Comment: Let's say I do, how can I implement it? I can add the names...

Comment: So, please recreate your CSV with the province for each festival. Then, feel free to post another question here. I (or anybody else) will show you how to wrap your CSV function inside your JSON function and then, manipulating the array with filter and map, creating another array with the names of the festivals for each province, which you can use in your tooltip.

Comment: I edited the question. The provinces are in the CSV provided.

Comment: What's the name of the field?

Comment: It is called locatienaam

Comment: I thought you said "locatienaam isn't the name of a province". Anyway, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a `festivals.csv` with the province for each event, these are the changes you'll have to do:

First, lets wrap your `csv` function inside your `json` function. That way, the data of your csv will be visible for the tooltip:

```
d3.json("amsterdam.json", function(data) {

    d3.csv("Festivals.csv", function(dataCsv) {

    //all your code for both functions goes here

    };

};
```

Please note that I wrote `dataCsv` for the data of the `csv` function. Feel free to change it.

Now, in your `mousemove` function for the tooltip:

```
.on('mousemove', function(d) {
                var mouse = d3.mouse(canvas.node()).map(function(d) {
                    return parseInt(d);
                });

                var province = d.properties.name;

                var provinceEvents = dataCsv.filter(function(d){
                    return d.locatienaam == province
                }).map(function(d){ return d.Title });

                tooltip.classed('hidden', false)
                    .attr('style', 'left:' + (mouse[0] + 15) +
                            'px; top:' + (mouse[1] - 35) + 'px')
                    .html(province + provinceEvents);
            })
```

Here, `provinceEvents` is an array of strings. You can easily manipulate it and create a list in your tooltip.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, I was modifying the csv. All of the 200+ events now have a Locatienaam, which matches one the province they are in. I followed your steps, thank you for that, but I still can't get it to work. There isn't anything showing up.

Comment: Try to `console.log` "province" and "provinceEvents" inside the mousemove function and tell me the errors that you get.

Comment: Province gives the right province, d.Locatienaam gives the right name, bur provinceEvents gives empty arrays. I checked if maybe somehow names don't match, but that is not the case. If I log d.Locatienaam == province, it sometimes returns true, but mostly return false. That is what is to be expected.

Comment: Check if you wrote locatienaam with capital L in the `var provinceEvents`. It should not be empty, I tested it.

Comment: Wrote it with capital.

Comment: What's the name of the data from the `csv` function? Can you log it inside the mousemove?

Comment: What do you mean of the data?

Comment: In my example, I used `dataCsv`. What did you use?

Comment: Same, also dataCsv

Comment: Can you log it inside the mousemove function? If you can, I really don't understand why provinceEvents is empty... maybe you should check  your CSV, it's really a huge one.

Comment: It seems that you have everything ready. It's really hard to me debug it from the distance. Try to apply first the filter, then the map, then filter and map together in provinceEvents, logging every step to catch the bug.

Comment: Shall I upload it for you, so you can look at it?

Comment: Better idea world be creating a fiddle or a Plunker.

Comment: Let me try that haha

Comment: Oh well, Plunker gives a bad request. But maybe you can do something with it... https://embed.plnkr.co/lA1LATNLhXAygfKbY3Gu/

Comment: Is it working? Beautiful! Do you get an array of provinces with provinceEvents? With all the events for the province?